# Getting a 422 Error on Post request, but I think my request is being sent correclty

Tags: javascript, post, http-status-code-422

I have to make a POST request, to an API that was given to me.

I am supposed to send some data to it and get back an `JWT` token.

The data i have to send is an object called `data` like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "address": "Lohmühlenstraße 65",
    "numberOfChildren": 2,
    "occupation": "EMPLOYED",
    "email": "jane.doe@getpopsure.com"
}
```

And the API docu looks like this:

```
curl https://challenge-dot-popsure-204813.appspot.com/user \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"firstName":"Jane","address":"Lohmühlenstraße 65","numberOfChildren":2,"occupation":"EMPLOYED","email":"jane.doe@getpopsure.com"}' \
-X POST
```

I am sending with axios a `POST` request, with an object, but i get an `422` Error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 ()`

This is my POST request, where `data` is the object above:

```
    axios.post('https://challenge-dot-popsure-204813.appspot.com/user', data)
    .then(function (response) {
      debugger
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Any ideas what can be the issue?

Comment: Have you seen what is there in `error` arg in catch block?

Comment: The issue could be with the special characters in the address `Lohmühlenstraße`, have you confirmed that the request sends properly in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or similar tool?

Comment: @segFault I just tried to do this post request in Postman - and it worked for me

Comment: Postman works for me too, I was unable to reproduce the issue in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xe9vIrOsWQVCwRxfs9Ip?p=preview). Perhaps the entire error response would be helpful to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the 422 error by removing or invalidating the JSON data. For instance remove/rename the "firstName" property.

Example:

```
{
    "name": "Jane",
    "address": "Lohmühlenstraße 65",
    "numberOfChildren": 2,
    "occupation": "EMPLOYED",
    "email": "jane.doe@getpopsure.com"
}
```

Resulted In: 422 Unprocessable Entity

```
{
    "errors": {
        "firstName": [
            "Missing data for required field."
        ],
        "name": [
            "Unknown field."
        ]
    }
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xe9vIrOsWQVCwRxfs9Ip?p=preview)

I think the issue you are facing is that the data you are expecting is not all there when you make the axios.post resulting in the error you are seeing. Make sure that the data sent in the request contains all valid fields and values beforehand.